# What counts as a client stream connection, the EventSources count?

Tags: javascript, flask, server-sent-events

I'm trying to minimize the number of concurrent connections my domain has to my backend server/api (via Server Sent Events - SSE), as I believe I'm hitting the "max" concurrent connections and causing delayed endpoint calls.

What I was going to do was on the Flask/backend side, "merging" some of my api calls into a single call and just returning a larger amount of data, than say 3 individual calls.

What I'm not sure on, is it the actual number of EventSource definitions I have in my js that creates the new connection? I liked having the 3 defined below as it makes it a bit more organized, but wasn't sure if this is what causes 3 distinct connections.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Three `EventSource` calls will be three dedicated sockets.

But, if you are using http/2 they should get multiplexed into a single socket. (See [Does Server-Sent Events Utilise HTTP/2 Pipelining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39274809/841830;) I think it is browser dependent.)

Comment: Thanks Darren - I'm using Flask as my backend, and from what I can tell, doesn't support http/2. And not to sound dumb, how do you actually "USE" http/2 (like instruct browser and server) to use http/2 instead? I'm running Flask in a Docker container.

Comment: I think you run a server that supports http/2, and the browser will auto-detect this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48510202/841830 for http/2 and Flask (though quite an old answer so something might have changed since then)